# Why does SonarQube code coverage report shows zero lines to cover when executed from jenkins file

Tags: c#, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm trying to get sonarQube code coverage report during build dotnet c# solution. For test purposes solution is really simple. It contains lib project and unit test project. Unit test covers one method of two defined in lib project. I use dotnet sonarscanner tool. When running locally next script

```
dotnet sonarscanner begin /d:sonar.login='myToken' /d:sonar.host.url='https://sbt-sonarqube.sigma.sbrf.ru' /k:SBERSPACE:backend /n:SBERSPACE:backend /d:sonar.branch.name='feature/TEAMX-3687-xunit-sonar' /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths='Tests/**/coverage.opencover.xml' /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths='Tests/**/TestResults.trx' /d:sonar.sourceEncoding='UTF-8'

dotnet build

dotnet test --logger "trx;LogFileName=TestResults.trx" /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover

dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login='myToken'
```

Everything works fine and at sonarQube host I see: code coverage 50% on 6 new lines.

But when I try do same insinde jenkins job (here is part of jenkinsfile):

```
def sonarExec
sonarExec = "dotnet sonarscanner"

withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'myCredentialId', passwordVariable: 'SonarPass', usernameVariable: 'SonarUser')]) {
    dir("SberSpace"){
        def SonarBeginCommand = """${sonarExec} begin /d:sonar.login=${SonarUser} /d:sonar.password=${SonarPass} /d:sonar.host.url=https://sbt-sonarqube.sigma.sbrf.ru /k:SBERSPACE:backend /n:SBERSPACE:backend \
                /d:sonar.branch.name=feature/TEAMX-3687-xunit-sonar \
                /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=Tests/**/coverage.opencover.xml \
                /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=Tests/**/TestResults.trx \
                /d:sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8"""

    exec(SonarBeginCommand)

    exec "dotnet build"
    
    exec "dotnet test --logger \"trx;LogFileName=TestResults.trx\" /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover"

    def endCommand = """${sonarExec} end /d:sonar.login=${SonarUser} /d:sonar.password=${SonarPass}"""

    exec(endCommand)
    }
}
```

I see empty code coverage on zero(!) new lines to cover.

Comment: Do `Tests/**/coverage.opencover.xml`  and `Tests/**/TestResults.trx` exists in the workspace? I also see you didn't wrap them in the single quotes. Maybe paths are interpreted.

Comment: @agabrys Yes, files are there:

18:22:57  Calculating coverage result...


18:22:57    Generating report 'C:\jenkins_slave\workspace\d_feature_TEAMX-3687-xunit-sonar\SberSpace\Tests\MyLib.Tests\coverage.opencover.xml'

Comment: And even sonar sees them:
18:23:17  INFO: Sensor C# Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp]
18:23:17  INFO: Parsing the OpenCover report C:\jenkins_slave\workspace\d_feature_TEAMX-3687-xunit-sonar\SberSpace\.\Tests\MyLib.Tests\coverage.opencover.xml
18:23:17  INFO: Adding this code coverage report to the cache for later reuse: C:\jenkins_slave\workspace\d_feature_TEAMX-3687-xunit-sonar\SberSpace\.\Tests\MyLib.Tests\coverage.opencover.xml
18:23:17  INFO: Coverage Report Statistics: 2 files, 2 main files, 2 main files with coverage, 0 test files, 0 project excluded files, 0 other language file

Comment: `Coverage Report Statistics: 2 files, 2 main files, 2 main files with coverage, 0 test files, 0 project excluded files, 0 other language file`, sounds that the coverage report files don't keep any coverage information.

Comment: Same output is for successful execution.